# how to find VLAN

Tags: ubuntu, local-area-network

i want to find whether our lab have the VLAN or not.

my various LAB ip addresses are

- 10.1.8.1
- 10.1.7.1
- 10.1.6.1
- 10.1.5.1
- 192.168.1.1

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your switch vendor, there's a couple of different methods you can use. Cisco supports a method called CDP (Cisco Discovery Protocol) which sends out packets every 60 seconds containing information about the connection. On Unix-like operating systems, you can view these with:

`tcpdump -vv -i eth0 -s 1500 -c 1 'ether[20:2] == 0x2000'`

With many other vendors, the Link Layer Discovery Protocol (LLDP) can be used. Like CDP, it broadcasts informational packets at a fixed interval, which you can sniff out and inspect. Since I've only ever worked with VLANs in Cisco shops, I'm not sure what you would use to view LLDP packets in any kind of user-friendly way.

Note that with even if your switch supports one of these protocols, it needs to actually be enabled on the switch.